# EXTJS - How to verify if element exists?

Tags: extjs

I need to know if a boxComponent exists in a ext formPanel in order to take some actions... Is there some way to know that?
something like this:

```
if(getElementById("boxId") != 'undefined' ){
    alert('exists');
}
```

Answer (score 16):

The common pattern that most people use is this:

```
var myBoxCmp = Ext.getCmp('cmpId');
if(myBoxCmp){
    myBoxCmp.doSomething();
}
```

Same thing for Elements:

```
var el = Ext.get('elId');
if(el){
    el.doSomething();
}
```

You can also use methods like `Container.findById`, but if you have an id (assuming it is unique, which it should be) just use `getCmp`.

EDIT: Several years have passed since this original answer, and nowadays `getCmp` is generally frowned upon as a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and should typically be avoided in applications (promotes global references, which generally indicate poor design when they are required). It's typically better to use controller references (if using MVC) or the various ComponentQuery or Container methods to reference related components (e.g. [down](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-down), [child](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-child), [getComponent](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-getComponent), etc.)

Comment: i have defined a panel with id. now when i add it to a border layout center region, how should i check whether it exists in center region or not? because it is defined as well..

Answer (score 3):

I just do it the extjs way and i prefer not to use getElementById() which is a native js method and may cause incompatibility issues in diffrenet browsers:

```
        if (!Ext.getCmp('componentid')) {
            alert('boxId is empty');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ext.get('boxId')`. It returns `null` if the object doesn't exist and returns an `Ext.Element` object.

Using `getElementById` would probably be much faster though. Do you have any specific objection against it?

Comment: Ext.get is a keyed lookup into a hash table, so it is basically just as fast as getElementById (and has the benefit of returning an Ext.Element instead of a DOM node, assuming that's the ultimate goal).

Comment: That is only a benefit the next time you execute it. The first time will still be slow. Then again, if speed is your goal than you probably wouldn't be using Ext JS :)

Comment: True.  Practically speaking though, if you are using Ext to begin with, there isn't much reason to go outside of its Element abstraction.  And by "faster" you're still only talking about a millisecond or two these days.

Comment: First of all thanks everyone. The problem has being solved.
I've tried all the ways of doing it. Good to know the diference between the way of finding the elements and the several methods to do so.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ext.isEmpty(object) method.

```
if(Ext.isEmpty(getElementById("boxId")) {
   alert('boxId is empty');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function openView(cid) {
    shortName = cid.substr(cid.lastIndexOf(".")+1, cid.length);
    if(Ext.get(shortName) == null) Ext.create(cid);
   Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp(shortName));
}
```

This function opens a view like

```
openView('MyApp.view.Oeffnungszeiten');
```

and if the View exists it accesses the old instance